# How Taylor series is compatible with special relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, mathematics, information, non-equilibrium

In mathematics, an **analytic** function is defined by its possession of a Taylor series with a positive radius of convergence ($R_c​>0$). Notably, certain analytic functions—such as holomorphic functions—exhibit an **infinite** radius of convergence. This intriguing property allows us to determine the function’s value at **all** points in the domain solely from the function value and its derivatives at a single reference point within its domain. It's worth noting that the reference point can be any point within the domain.

**Old Part**

However, a paradox emerges: If we modify the function’s value at this reference point, the function values at all other points—spanning from negative infinity to positive infinity, if the domain is unbounded—seemingly adjust **instantaneously** via the Taylor series relation. Doesn’t this apparent instantaneous influence challenge the fundamental principle that information cannot propagate faster than light?

If not, why does this behavior not violate causality? If it does, how can we reconcile it with our understanding of information propagation?

To clarify, by **information**, we refer to all the data necessary to determine the function’s value and its rate of change at each point in the domain. I'm unsure whether the finiteness of the propagation speed applies to this kind of information at all. I would greatly appreciate it if you could also provide your insights on this matter.

**New Part**

Edit to rephrase my question:

If physical functions are regarded as analytic (having a Taylor series with a non-zero radius of convergence), how can we reconcile the property of instantaneous update within the radius of convergence for Taylor series (for analytical functions) with the fact that information transfer speed is limited within the domain of physical functions due to special relativity?

My humble speculation is that during dynamical evolution (in non-steady-state situations), physical functions may lose their strict analyticity, implying their associated Taylor series have an extremely short radius of convergence to avoid violating causality. Within this framework, perturbing a physical system disrupts the validity of its Taylor series expansion (and its analyticity). Consequently, not all parts of the function's domain are instantaneously affected by the initial perturbation, as the Taylor series relation no longer holds. I'm not sure about my idea.

Thank you to everyone for aiding in my deeper understanding of this concept.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152277/discussion-on-question-by-omid-how-taylor-series-is-compatible-with-special-rela); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 5):

A function is a mathematical object. Mathematical objects only exist in human minds, not in the physical universe. Thus, a function may have any properties consistent with your axiom system.

Imagine that you're studying an exoplanet 100 light years away. You have a function that models its orbit. Then, you get more data and you use it to make a better model of the orbit, a modified function. Does the fact that the planet is 100 light years away mean that you must wait to use your new model?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I’m not quite convinced by your answer. It would be great if you could kindly elaborate, because your answer is more like a philosophical point of view.

Comment: @Omid I suggest you read Reuben Hersh's excellent book, "What Is Mathematics, Really?"

Comment: I really liked the newly added part. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the nice book suggestion. I noticed we often have the same view regarding things/questions like this, so I am looking forward to read it.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a physical object of a certain shape. You measure it in a finite region around you.

To the best of your ability, you estimate a mathematical analytic curve that fits the shape of the object.

As time goes by, you receive more information about the shape of distant regions of the physical object. You learn how well your curve fits. Perhaps you refine the curve.

Answer (score 0):

Real physical systems are dynamical. That is, their observable properties change with time in addition to varying spatially. In particular, the dynamics are causal: changes to the conditions of the system in one region of space propagate through to the rest of the system at a limited speed. This is an empirical fact, but also a feature of the mathematics that we use to model our systems. The models are not as simple as Taylor series that respond instantaneously to changes in data at one point in space; they depend on space and time in a way that respects causality.

For a concrete example, consider a taut string stretched horizontally between two posts at either end. If we jiggle one of the posts up and down, we alter the value of the string's displacement at one end. This affects all the other points along the string, but not instantaneously. The effect of our jiggling proceeds along the string at the wave speed of the string. In our mathematical model for the string, the string displacement is a solution to a wave equation, and such solutions have the property that the displacement at any point in the string is affected causally by changes in the displacement at other points in the string.

Comment: I understand your point and agree. However, I struggle with implementing this concept into the Taylor series expansion. Consider writing the mathematical function representing the displacement of the string from the horizontal line just before perturbing it at x=0. When you perturb it at this point, the Taylor series suggests that this change is instantaneously transmitted. Yet, from physics and observations, we know that it takes time. How can we reconcile these two conclusions?

Comment: And if this contradiction cannot be reconciled, when exactly are we justified in utilizing Taylor series? Perhaps only in scenarios of steady state?